# Linear Algebra - eigenvalue and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have two questions which I have trouble to prove/disprove.

1) I have trouble to prove this:

- $A$ is $n \times n$ matrix, if $A^2=A$ then A has at least one eigenvalue.

2) I have trouble to disprove this:

- If A characteristic polynomial is $t^2-2t+1$ then $A^2$ characteristic polynomial is $t^4-4t^2+1$.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: For the second one see [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix). The first one makes perfect sense as it is, but seems to be missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) First dispose of the case where $A=0$. Then show that $Ax=x$ has a non-trivial solution by taking $x=Av$ for some $v$ for which $Av\ne 0$.

2) Realize that it's absolutely nonsense by remembering that the degree of the characteristic polynomial of an $n\times n$ matrix is $n$. So, if $A$ has characteristic polynomial $t^2+\cdots $, then $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix for $n=?$. And then $A^2$ is an $n\times n$ matrix for $n=?$. So its characteristic polynomial is certainly not $t^4+\cdots $. So all you need is to exhibit a matrix $A$ whose characteristic polynomial is the quadratic given.

EDIT (solution to 1 without using minimal/characteristic polynomial, since there really is no need): Assuming $A\ne 0$, there exists some $v$ with $x=Av\ne 0$. Now $Ax=AAv=A^2v=Av=x$ and therefore $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue with eigenvector $x=Av$.

Comment: I understood why 2 is wrong, but I don't quite understood 1 I'll be glad if you can expend your answer an eigenvalue is when $$Av=\lambda v$$ The case when $A = 0$ is when the matrix is zero which means the eigenvalue is zero, in case $A \neq 0$ I need to show that $$A^2v = Av = \lambda v$$

Comment: @JaVaPG see my edit to the answer.

Comment: All understood!:) Thank you-Toda Raba.

Answer (score 2):

1) $A^2 = A$ means $p(x)=x^2-x=x(x-1)$ anihilates the matrix. Then $m_A(x)$, the minimal polynomial of A, divides $p(x)$: then $m_A(x)=x, x-1$ or $x(x-1)$. Therefore, at least one of $0,1$ is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

2) If $A$ is $n \times n$ then its characteristic polynomial has degree $n$.
So, if $2\neq4$ then 2) is false because $A^2 \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$

1) $A(A-$Id$)=0$ then:

- $A=0$ $\Rightarrow$ OK
- $A\neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$  $t-1$ divides is minimal polynomial so $1$ is an eigenvalue.